# Gulf Arabic vowels allophones

Tags: phonology, phonetics, vowels, arabic, allophones

No matter how much I browse, I cannot find any true researcher's really precise and accurate data on the issue. Actually, I cannot find any Gulf Arabic Phonology compendium, so any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try a textbook, such as [Teach Yourself Gulf Arabic](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Yourself-Arabic-Complete-Course-Package/dp/0071434534/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1381139845&sr=8-5&keywords=gulf+arabic). This series tends to be pretty good, so even though it's not an academic source in the narrow sense I think it's quite reliable.

Comment: Have you looked it up in [*The Encyclopedia of Arabic Language and Linguistics*](http://referenceworks.brillonline.com/browse/encyclopedia-of-arabic-language-and-linguistics) or [Al-Ani 1970](https://www.degruyter.com/view/product/137511?rskey=9iQJOC&result=1)?

Answer (score -3):

if you learn Arabic you will be able to adapt to any of the Arabic dialects, all Arabic dialect use the same Phonology with some minor exception like some letter imported from other languages mostly the sound `g` rather than `j(ج) or ق`, or switching some letter like `a(أ)` rather than `ق`. so i recommend you to learn Arabic.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. Even if all Arabic dialects use the same phonology (distribution of phonemes) - which I doubt is strictly true - The OP is asking about allophones, which are certainly not constant around the Arabophone world. You are also making the unwarranted assumption that the OP does not already speak Arabic.